# Convert to .war file in java

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, war

I am trying to work on web sockets in Java. For deploying the server socket on glassfish ,I need to create a .war file.

I have a folder which contains a .java file for the websocket server, an html file, and a javascript file.

How can I convert this folder to a .war file to be deployable on glassfish server?

OR

How to convert a simple .java file to .war file ? I have tried executing

```
jar -cvf foldername.war* command, but it did not work .
```

Is it required to convert the .java file to .jar file first ??

**EDIT **

The server code uses the javax.websocket.* class files . So i had downloaded
the jar files from the internet and specified the class path to the path of websocket class files during compilation .I also added one dependency for websocket in the pom.xml inside the META-INF folder of zipped file i donwloaded for the jar files. The code has compiled and .class file is created. Now i used following command and .war file is created .

jar -cvf warname.war classname.class htmalfile.html javascriptfile.jsp

This .war file only contains above three file and META-INF folder .It does not possess web-inf folder . It does not has the structure the .war file should have ,as i have googled . So , even if it is deployed on the glassfish server , the server endpoint is not running when i hit the url localhost:8080/warname .

So , i need to know where am i going wrong in creating the war file? Am i doing any mistake in linking the .java file to the javax.websocket.* class files ?

Kindly help me with this.TIA..:)

**EDIT AGAIN***

I HAVE CREATED A MAVEN PROJECT ,USING STANDARD "mvn archetype:generate" command ,and the project is created with the required structure . Then i pasted my CustomEndPoint.class(server socket class) in **WEB-INF/classes** folder and also **server_html.html** , **server_html.jsp** in **webapp** folder . I also updated pom.xml file to update dependency for **javax.websocket-api** .

Then i executed command **mvn package** in the folder in which pom.xml file is there. Then **webapp.war** package is created . I am attaching the screenshots for the above developments. But still the code is not running on the glassfish server post deployment .

[Screenshot of maven project creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf2aV.png)

[Screenshot of maven project creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoGSC.png)

[Directory structure of war file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtq5A.png)

[Where .class file is contained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzqd8.png)

[pom.xml file update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GsNd.png)

[glassfish server deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e51qa.png)

Comment: are you providing space between `war` and `*`?, also where's the web-inf folder

Comment: Your question is overly broad.

Comment: RamanIfc , i used following command to convert imto war files  jar -cvf warname.war classname.java htmlname.html javascriptfile.jsp                                                    This command created the war file but , it does not contain any Web-Inf file.It just contains above 3 files . Dts why , though i am able to deploy it on the glassfish server , the code is not running .                   Whats wrong i am doing in creating the war file ??

Comment: BrentR , i am not able to convert the 3 files to war file properly because the created war file does not follow the structure that war files should have . It does not contain web-inf file . That is why the server code is not running on the glassfish when i am trying to hit url localhost :8080/warname

Comment: Well yea .... that's right.  If you really want to create a WAR file using the `jar` command, then you need to prepare a file tree with the correct structure *before* you tell the `tar` command to create the WAR file.  But this is not a good way to do it.  (And you need to compile .java files first ...).  Read up on build tools like Ant, Maven and Gradle which understand how to assemble a WAR file with the correct structure.

Comment: This is why we are saying this question is Too Broad.

Comment: Stephen C , I have compiled the .java file to .class file .and i had executed that jar command with .class file instead of .java file . Thanks , I shall read about maven then .

Comment: I have edited the question with latest developments . please check

Answer (score 0):

Convert a Java Web Application (a WAR file) to a Desktop App

http://gotz.web.unc.edu/2017/06/03/convert-a-java-web-application-a-war-file-to-a-desktop-app/